# How can I sort by an attribute of a key property in Google Cloud/Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Using the following `ndb` model classes:

```
class Product(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    barcode = ndb.StringProperty()

class Donation(ndb.Model):
    user= ndb.UserProperty()
    product = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Product)
```

When using a query such as:

```
donations = Donation.query().order(Donation.product).fetch(1000)
```

How can I sort the resulting `donations` by `Product name` or `barcode`?

Comment: `Donation.query().order(Donation.product).order(Donation.name).fetch(1000)`

Comment: Try to sort by code. sorted(donations, key=lambda d: d.product)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do such query, at least not with the datastore. The sort order can only be one of the respective entity model's properties.

Every query needs one or more corresponding datastore [indexes](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes). For ordered queries you need [composite indexes](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes#composite_indexes), defined in the [`index.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/indexref) file. Each such index has exactly one `kind` in its definition, you can't mix multiple entity types (`Donation` with `Product` in your case).

If you *need* such queries you can duplicate the necessary info and fill it in when you update the `product` property. Also if/when the respective `Product`'s properties change you may need to update all `Donation` entities referencing it.

A maybe acceptable middle ground would be to use the actual `product` property value (the key itself) to order the query - at least you'd have all the donations linked to the same product entity grouped together.